# GridView in Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net-4.0, asp.net-4.0

I have an table in SQL with path for folders Ex: N:\Group ISIT Security\LAN\
I need this path transforming in Menu and Submenus in an webapp.
Ex:
An GridList with the main folder

N:\

and, I click expand this menu for:

\Group ISIT Security\

Other developer, created this navegation with Telerik Components, but I can't used this.
Does anyone know a method for this in JQUery, Javascript or Asp.Net?

Ex:
Column in SQL:
Folder_Path
N:\A\B\X\Z\

In Menu: expanding until the final path.

N:\

--A\

---B\

----X\

-----Z\

Comment: This is a little unclear. Can you please post the code that you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `asp:TreeView`:

```
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server">
</asp:TreeView>
```

code behind:

```
String p="N:\\A\\B\\X\\Z\\";
String[] res = Regex.Split(p, @"(?<=[\\])");
TreeNode parent=null;
for (int i = 0; i < res.Length; i++)
    {

       if (i == 0)
       {
          TreeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(res[i]));
          parent=TreeView1.Nodes[0];
       }
       else
       {
          if(parent.ChildNodes.Count!=0)
              parent = parent.ChildNodes[0];
          parent.ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode(res[i]));
       }
    }
```

that will give you this:

[image]